# How to apply errorpolicy to useSubscription hook with apollo-client?

Tags: error-handling, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, subscription

I want to apply 'errorpolicy: all' on a useSubscription hook in my React Native app. In the apollo documentation there is no field for errorpolicy in the options that useSubscription accepts as there is for useQuery.

I would like to get the data from the subscription even if there was a graphql-error like I am able to with my queries. How can I achieve this?

useSubscription options:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#options

useQuery options:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#options